# Effect of Steric Hindrance in Pinacol-Pinacolone Rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

In the acid catalysed rearrangement of vicinal diols to carbonyl compounds which is pinacol-pinacole rearrangement,
The migratory order of the groups is H>Aryl>Alkyl
My question is that how aryl groups take precedence over alkyl groups when the aryl groups cause steric hindrance.

Comment: For an aryl group, what if the *ipso*-carbon is bound to both carbons in question at same time in the transition state for rearrangement? What becomes of the positive charge?